# How can make objects invisible in only certain areas?

Tags: fluid-simulation

[image]

I started to study blender recently, and I was just making some experiments with fluid simulation but I was stuck with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the boolean modifier to achieve this. Put it after the fluid simulation modifier for the domain object, set its operation to difference and the target object to the region you want to hide.

[image]